# Laravel socket io laravel-echo: get number of subscribed users to channel

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am building a real time application by Laravel echo server, socket.io, redis. I need to know how many users are subscribing to a certain channel. How can I do that?

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is described here: https://pusher.com/tutorials/online-presence-laravel. Basically, you send an event to server when user joins, and you send an event when a user leaves. You can set a value on the user to see it is online. Then you can select all users who are online or count them.

Answer (score 2):

See [Joining Presence Channels](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting#joining-presence-channels) and take note of the `here` method of the `channel` it returns and array list of `users` online.

You can use `users.length` to get the online user count and set it in a variable.

Then you need to use the `joining` and `leaving` hooks to increment (++) and decrement (--) the counter.

```js
const totalOnline = 0;

Echo.join(`chat.${roomId}`)
    .here((users) => {
        totalOnline = users.length
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        totalOnline++;
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        totalOnline--;
    });
```

Comment: I need to know the nubber of users in server side

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redis#interacting-with-redis <- Query the Redis database, You will have to figure this out, I have never had a reason to query the Redis database to pull out info belonging to laravel-echo.
But why do you need this number server side?

Comment: There are some drivers that become online via android application. Once a request of delivering a package from a user is given, I need to find the closest driver to deliver the package to a destination. So when NewRequest event is fired, I broadcast to all subscribed drivers and ask them to post their location. Posting all locations may take afew seconds but I don't know how long does it take. So If I know how many drivers are online (or subscribed) then I know how long should I wait for posts which give me the locations.

Comment: Can't the app post driver location every few minutes while it is open? Then you would know who is online and where with persistence.

Comment: In this way no socket is needed. We don't know when a request is sent. It may take 30 minutes or even an hour for a request. Why should I make the server so busy for a request that happens very rarely? 
We also need to implement map tracking. For map tracking you are right, because I am sure the driver is moving and some thing new happens. But when waiting for a request, your solution is very inefficient.